# Prepend array of to array of DOM elements

Tags: jquery

I've HTML form, and array of text matches the exact count of label tag in the form.

Form:

```
<label id="1">First</label>
<label id="2">Second</label>
<label id="3">Second</label>
<label id="4">Third</label>
<label id="5">Fourth</label>
<label id="6">Fifth</label>
<label id="7">Fifth</label>
<label id="8">Fifth</label>
```

Array

```
X1
X2
X3
X4
X5
```

How to loop through the form, get the list of labels in it, and prepend the list of text as span inside the label. also to check if the text start with some text (to check the duplicate) and prepend the same value of the first element. as described in the below example, the final form must be like this:

```
<label id="1"><span>X1</span>First</label>
<label id="2"><span>X2</span>Second</label>
<label id="3"><span>X2</span>Second</label>
<label id="4"><span>X3</span>Third</label>
<label id="5"><span>X4</span>Fourth</label>
<label id="6"><span>X5</span>Fifth</label>
<label id="7"><span>X5</span>Fifth</label>
<label id="8"><span>X5</span>Fifth</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `each` and `html` methods to iterate and get/set the HTML of the elements. Instead of having an array with the `X...` values, I suggest having a map between strings and these values. See the example below:

```js
var map = {
    "First": "X1",
    "Second": "X2",
    "Third": "X3",
    "Fourth": "X4",
    "Fifth": "X5"
};
$("label").each(function (i) {
   var $this = $(this)
   var html = $this.html();
   var newText = map[html];
   
   $this.html("<span>" + newText + "</span> " + html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="1">First</label>
<label id="2">Second</label>
<label id="3">Second</label>
<label id="4">Third</label>
<label id="5">Fourth</label>
<label id="6">Fifth</label>
<label id="7">Fifth</label>
<label id="8">Fifth</label>
```

As alternative, you may want to use the `prepend` function to add the `span` elements:

```
$this.prepend("<span>" + newText + "</span> ");
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly, but i've edited the question to add more details and another issue.

Comment: @AhmadZoughbi You're welcome! See the edit. You don't need an array but an object.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and [.prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) functions.

For example, this will work:

```
<script>
    var arr = [ 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5' ];
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "label" ).each(function ( index ) {
            $(this).prepend("<span>" + arr[index] + "</span>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can do this even simpler and without having to maintain the array:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "label" ).each(function ( index ) {
            var t = index+1;
            $(this).prepend("<span>X" + t + "</span>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Update:** 
Note, this solution only applies to a numeric array with continous keys (1-9). If you need another order ("1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5" as in your question"), I suggest that you follow the solution proposed by Ionică Bizău.

Comment: He needs a map between string numbers (e.g. *"First"*) and numbers (e.g. `1`). Your code will not handle that...

Comment: arr[index] in the first example will do just that. Please elaborate?

Comment: For index `2`, you will have `X3`, but expected is `X2` (because the HTML is `"Second"`).

Comment: No, "index" begins at 1 (tested in Firefox). Did you test this?

Comment: What's the final HTML after running this code? You may want to add a JSFiddle link or demo in your answer. :)

Comment: Final code is as requested by AhmadZoughbi: '<label id="1"><span>X1</span>First</label>' etc.

Comment: `X1First X2Second X3Second X4Third X5Fourth undefinedFifth undefinedFifth undefinedFifth`–compare it with the OP code. :) Hope you got what I'm trying to say here. :D See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrf4nqx8/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91295/discussion-between-kristoffer-bohmann-and-ionic-bizu).